# File read write mode "r+" unexpected behavior in C

Tags: c, debugging, fopen

In the following code, I am searching for a '.' in my template to paste a string after it. For some reason, although the string is pasted as expected, it deletes some text from my template. I do not have an idea where the problem could be. Tried fflush() with no good effect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    int tmp_char, tmp_offset;
    char file_name[50] = "FileIoTest_template.txt";
    char tmp_string1[50] = "Generic String 1";
    char tmp_string2[50] = "Generic String 2";
    long tmp_long;

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r+");
    //fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    do {
        tmp_char = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c ", tmp_char);
        if (tmp_char == '.')
           break;
    } while (tmp_char != EOF);
    tmp_long = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, tmp_long, SEEK_SET);
    tmp_offset = strlen(tmp_string1);
    fputs(tmp_string1, fp);
    fputs("\n", fp);
    //fflush(fp);

    fseek(fp, tmp_long+tmp_offset, SEEK_SET);
    do {
        tmp_char = fgetc(fp);
        printf("%c ", tmp_char);
        if (tmp_char == '.')
            break;
    } while (tmp_char != EOF);
    tmp_long = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, tmp_long, SEEK_SET);
    fputs(tmp_string2, fp);
    fputs("\n", fp);
    //fflush(fp);

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my template, "FileIoTest_template.txt":

```
Sample list:
1.
2.
3.
random text

4.
5.
6.

bunch of random text
```

The output of my code is:

```
Sample list:
1.Generic String 1
ext

4.Generic String 2
of random text
```

Comment: It's as if you think `fputs` _inserts_ content into a file. It doesn't; it just overwrites whatever is currently there (at the current position).

Comment: It doesn't "delete", it simply overwrites your existing data with new one. If you want insertion, you need to do it yourself.

Comment: Ii may have overwritten data . As you use `r+` mode so it wont delete any data already present . So see if you position cursor correctly .

Comment: One solution I can think of is placeholder text. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot easily modify a file by inserting data into the middle of it without replacing anything that's already there.  You would need to overwrite the whole file, from the insertion point to the end (past the *original* end to whatever point the new end needs to be).  It is tricky to do so correctly, and it is unsafe to try, for if the process is interrupted in the middle then your file is trashed.

Usually, one instead creates a new version of the file contents in a temporary file, and once that is completed successfully, one replaces the original file with the new one.

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was to assume that file write operations insert text, which in hindsight seems stupid.